# gps location on android

Tags: android, gps, location

i am trying to make location app on android
when i run the app on emulator and send fake longitude and latitude it show longitude and latitude in logs but when i run it on my phone it does not give me current location cordinates or any output in logs
here is my code

```
    public void getLocation(){

    final LocationManager manager= (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener listener= new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            loc=new ArrayList<SetLoc>();
            SetLoc vari= new SetLoc();
            double longitude=location.getLongitude();
            double latitude=location.getLatitude();
            String lng=""+longitude;
            String lat=""+latitude;

            Log.d("onLocationChange", lng+" "+lat );

            vari.setlon(lng);
            Log.d("setlon", "setting the longitude"+lng);
            vari.setlat(lat);
            loc.add(vari);


            String url="http://10.16.49.234:8080/WebApplication6/webresources/generic";


            sendcord(lng,lat,url);

            Log.d("onchangelocation", "aftersnd.execute()");

        }
    };
    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);


}`
```

help please

Comment: Please post your manifest too..

Comment: Check for permissions in the manifest...

Comment: `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

Comment: note that `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` implies `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` so you don't have to specify both.

Comment: Ya that's right @darnmason

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i have included both these permissions

Comment: plz give me some solution i very worried

Comment: Are you sure your onLocationChanged() is being called???

Comment: when i use emulator n send fake cordinates onLocationChanged() gets called n it shows cordinates in logs but when i run app on mobile it doesn't give the current location or any thing

Comment: Is your GPS getting fixed when you run it in real device or is it still blinking????

Comment: no it keeps on blinking

Comment: Do one thing..Show your device to open sky for a minute or two while running the app..This will fix the gps..Try it..

Comment: thanks alot @Lal
it worked

Comment: I'll add that as my answer..Kindly mark it as accepted..

Comment: hey @Lal can i  please have your email id for help as i am beginner and often come across very basic little errors

Comment: It will marked as spam if i give you my email id..You can ask Stack Overflow if you have any doubts..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seem perfect, I assume you are getting Null because there is no previous GPS value in your device. Do this,

Load the application in your device, move to **open sky**, run the application, wait for 2 minutes. Come back to office inside, and then execute above code

**OR**

Run the application in **open sky**..

Answer (score 1):

You're specifically requesting GPS data, are you sure that it is enabled on the device you are testing on?

Have you looked into the fused location provider bundled with Google Play Services? With this provider you can immediately retrieve the last known location and request updates in a battery efficient way as multiple apps communicate with Google Play Services instead of directly with the device's sensors.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Comment: He said that his app is working fine when tested in emulator..That means his providers and listeners are working perfecly.. @darnmason

Comment: @Lal I understand that the code was working on the emulator by setting the GPS coordinates manually, which is why I suggested the issue was with the settings on the actual device. Then I went one step further by suggesting a better solution to the problem. I don't think "go outside to get a clear view of the sky for a few minutes" is an adequate answer. Even if the app is designed for outdoor use it should still be usable with little to no GPS signal. The Location API that I referenced does the work of switching between available location providers for you.